# Is it possible to use raw sockets with Twisted (Python)

Tags: python, sockets, networking, twisted, raw-sockets

I am writing an implementation of an NAT and have the need to use raw sockets.  I have become accustomed to the Twisted architecture and like how it handles concurrent connections.

Data coming into a Twisted protocol is manipulated, NATed, tabulated, and sent out the raw socket.  Data coming into the raw socket is manipulated, looked up, NATed, and directed to the appropriate protocol instance.

Would having a single raw socket suffice?  What if a large number of connections came in at the same time.  Doesn't twisted handle that, or is twisted pretty much a non advantage in connectionless protocols.  If there is an advantage could anyone direct me to a raw sockets twisted example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twisted supports connectionless protocols just fine.  See, for example, [`listenUDP`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorUDP.listenUDP.html).

There are modules for manipulating IP-level protocol data in `twisted.pair`, but not all of it works; [in particular, tuntap support does not work](http://tm.tl/6169).

There are no examples of this that I know of, but as I understand it, a single raw socket should be fine.  You will, however, need to write your own transport, wrapping the socket up in an [`IReadDescriptor` / `IWriteDescriptor` and using `IReactorFDSet`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorFDSet.html).  However, if you're adept enough to know you need raw sockets in the first place, this shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more about that last part? More concretely my issue is I want to send UDP on addresses 0.0.0.0 and listen on 255.255.255.255 (DHCP related). I want to use twisted because this is something that has to simulate many clients, not just one DHCP client.

Comment: I would be happy to, but can you phrase a more specific question?  If you've read the documentation for those interfaces, what part is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

Dig around in the twisted source code and you'll find [twisted.pair](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/pair/index.html), which isn't really maintained anymore, but gives you about 90% of what you need to do raw sockets.

I have some example code somewhere showing how to use /dev/bpf on BSD with it. The only caveat is that it's pure python so no tcpdump-style packet filters (port 80 and host blah.com) - you just have to drink from the fire hose.

Comment: It's true twisted.pair doesn't see a lot of work but I'll argue that it is maintained since I have spent quite a number of hours on it myself over the past year. :)  It's a challenging area and so far there haven't been any releaseable results - but I hope to get some improvements into Twisted 14.0!

Comment: My apologies - no offense was intended! :p The last time I looked at twisted.pair was probably around 12.0 so I'll have to refamiliarize myself.